# Proper use of Camel Aggregator "to" URIs

Tags: java, apache-camel, aggregation

I have a route where I want Camel to visit the following beans:

1. First, `loggingBean`
2. Second, an `aggregator` that waits for a certain number of messages to aggregate on it
3. Once the Aggregator's `completionSize` is reached (3), keep going to #4
4. Third, `processorBean`
5. And fourth/last, `finalizerBean`

Here is my route:

```
<route id="my-camel-route"> 
    <from uri="direct:starter" />

    <to uri="bean:loggingBean?method=shutdown" />

    <aggregate strategyRef="myAggregationStrategy" completionSize="3">
        <correlationExpression> 
            <simple>${header.id} == 1</simple> 
        </correlationExpression>
        <to uri="bean:processorBean?method=process" /> 
    </aggregate> 

    <to uri="bean:finalizerBean?method=shutdown" />
</route>
```

My question: do I need to place `finalizerBean` **inside** the `<aggregate>` element like so:

```
<aggregate strategyRef="myAggregationStrategy" completionSize="3">
    <correlationExpression> 
        <simple>${header.id} == 1</simple> 
    </correlationExpression>
    <to uri="bean:processorBean?method=process" /> 
    <to uri="bean:finalizerBean?method=shutdown" /> 
</aggregate>
```

Basically, I'm wondering if the way I currently have things will prompt Camel to send the message to the aggregator, and then *also* send it on to `finalizerBean` (essentially, bypassing the aggregator). In my case, I want it to aggregate until `completionSize` is 3, and *then* send the aggregated exchange on to the `processorBean` and then finally `finalizerBean`.

Or have I configured this correctly? What's the difference between `finalizerBean` being inside the `<aggregate>` element vs being outside it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second example is correct.

```
<aggregate strategyRef="myAggregationStrategy" completionSize="3">
    <correlationExpression> 
        <simple>${header.id} == 1</simple> 
    </correlationExpression>
    <to uri="bean:processorBean?method=process" /> 
    <to uri="bean:finalizerBean?method=shutdown" /> 
</aggregate>
```

If finalizerBean is "outside" the `<aggregate>`, it will get executed for every message that comes from `direct:starter` - which isn't what you want ;)

Comment: And how do we express the same thing using the Java DSL? Does `aggregate().to()` do what I expect, namely sending the aggregated exchange only once to the named route?

Comment: Right, something like `aggregate(new MyStrategy()).completionSize(3).to("bean:xyz")` would be the equivalent.